# How to sort an Access DB Table, via VBA, displayed in order when opened by using the Navigation Pane

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

As an end of some inserts, via VBA script, I have been doing in an ACCESS table. I have as a requirement to order the table by a field. So a third person would open it via the ACCESS Navigation Pane and it would be shown in the specified order.
EDIT: I also need that table to be writable by this third person.

I can think about creating a new table, using an SQL sentence to order it. But it seems like a very ugly option.

Is there any way to archive it using a DAO object or other VBA approach?

Comment: You don't need to create a new table, you just need to create a saved Select Query (also known as a "View" in other database applications) and specify the required sort order there.

Comment: Thanks. That would work if it weren’t because I also need that table to be writable by these third people.I forgot to mention it in the question, I'll edit it.

Comment: If the saved query ("view") is based on a single table and only affects the sort order then it will most likely be editable.

Comment: You are right!! It's fanny, I have never tried before because I had no idea that could be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query which sorts the table is the cleanest solution.

If you don't want to create an extra object for that, you can set the table sorting with DAO properties like this:

```
Sub DoIt()

    Call TableSetSort("myTable", "myField")

End Sub

' Set a table to be sorted by <sFieldname>
Public Sub TableSetSort(sTable As String, sFieldname As String)

    Dim DB As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim prop As DAO.Property

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = DB.TableDefs(sTable)

    ' Set field to order by
    Call TableAddProperty(tdf, "OrderBy", dbText, sFieldname)
    ' These two may be true by default, but better safe than sorry
    Call TableAddProperty(tdf, "OrderByOn", dbBoolean, True)
    Call TableAddProperty(tdf, "OrderByOnLoad", dbBoolean, True)

    ' if you want to debug
    For Each prop In tdf.Properties
        Debug.Print prop.Name, prop.Value
    Next prop

End Sub

' Set or add a property in a TableDef
Public Sub TableAddProperty(tdf As DAO.TableDef, sName As String, iType As DAO.DataTypeEnum, vValue As Variant)

    Dim prop As DAO.Property

    ' Try to set the property value, this will fail with Runtime Error 3270 if the property doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    tdf.Properties(sName) = vValue

    If Err.Number = 3270 Then
        ' Property doesn't exist yet - create and append it
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set prop = tdf.CreateProperty(sName, iType, vValue)
        tdf.Properties.Append prop
    End If
    ' Note: error handling here is quite minimal!

End Sub
```